# Form with service and lunch times

Tags: forms, gui-design, datetimepicker

Consider a form with service time and lunch time information. And the user can customize the settings for day of the week.

I have two alternatives:

A form for each day of week

[image: A form for each day of week]

A form with all days that can be replicated
[image: A form with all days that can be replicated]

What is the best alternative? How can I improve the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is the best alternative?**

Use the second alternative, with all days initially selected, and ***without*** the 'add other configuration' button.

When the user deselects a day, automatically select that day in the configuration below (creating a new configuration if there is not already one below).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Drmw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(also remember to deselect a day if the user selects it in different section)

> **How can I improve the form?**

By using sliders, instead of making the user type in the times. These require much less effort to interact with, and provide a visual indication of the time selected.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0A4O6.png)</sup>

Comment: As per my understanding the user should have the flexibility to specify Service + Lunch times for all day of the week. So wondering, how will the user enter the timings for all day except Wednesday (unchecked) in your form 1?

Comment: Perhaps OP can confirm if that is the case? I guess if this is the required scenario, then the user would have to uncheck the second wednesday as well - which is not great. (Best leave the dayless row below as things would get even more fiddly if it were removed).

Comment: Well, in my design the user can add or remove rows.